# Binding a custom View to a Point

Tags: android, view, binding, components

I have a `View` and this view contains a `Point`. I would like to bind data to this point, but as far as I understand I cannot create a custom attribute in `attrs.xml` with a `Point` as the format.

This is the view:

```
public class MyView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    private Point point;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Point getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    public void setPoint(Point point) {
        this.point = point;
    }
}
```

And this is MyObject:

```
public class MyObject extends BaseObservable {
    private Point point;

    @Bindable
    public Point getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    public void setPoint(Point point) {
        this.point = point;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.point);
    }
}
```

And now I want to bind MyView something like this:

```
<MyView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:point="@{myObject.point}"/>
```

and an `attrs.xml` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyView">
        <attr name="point" format="Point" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

But that does not seem to be possible. Does somebody know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around for this problem. Instead of binding to a `Point`, I created

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyView">
        <attr name="pointX" format="integer" />
        <attr name="pointY" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And then I bound the values of `myObject.getPoint().x` to `pointX` and `myObject.getPoint().y` to `pointY`. This is not the most beautiful solution, but it works.